# How reduce space in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have this code : i want reduce the space (see Figure)

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `\title[Managerial Economics\vspace{-1em}]{VW Invasion of North America}`? Sometimes it works.  Another similar hack could be `\section[\mbox{}\\[-2em] Section 1]{Section 1}`

Comment: @ParthaD. not working, other idea please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space contains the author name (but you don't provide `\author`).

You can redefine the `sidebar left` template to remove author and to reduce vertical spaces:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Managerial Economics]{VW Invasion of North America} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\institute[FDSM] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textit{Fudan Business} \\\textit{School of Management} \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
%\textit{bofu20131@163.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
      \vskip1.5em%
      \hskip3pt%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
      \insertshorttitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
      \vskip.25em%
    }%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```